# Multiple Excel Spreadsheets linked to one Access Table without a macro

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have multiple excel spreadsheets that have the same fields and table structure. I want to link them all to one table in Access without using a macro, so that when any updates are made in the excel files they automatically update in the Access table. Can this be done? I am able to link one excel table to one Access table but not multiple excel tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

But you can link all Excel files separately, and then create a UNION query that contains all the linked tables.

Then work with this UNION query, it will contain all records from all tables.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Andre.